# Indexing excluded directories in PyCharm 3

Tags: pycharm

I am trying to exclude some directories from Pycharm's project index as they are recursive symbolic links. I have excluded the directories and invalidated the caches and restarted but PyCharm still indexes these excluded directories. It does *not* result in duplicate results in my search results etc. but indexing takes so much longer.

Is there a way to exclude these directories from being indexed?

Comment: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-52055

Comment: @LazyOne I think that deserves a full answer as PyCharm still suffers from the issue in 2021. :/

Answer (score 53):

if i am right: File | Settings | project structure and select the folders you need and click exlcuded.

from [documentation](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/project-structure-dialog.html)

> Mark a folder as an excluded root.
>
> Excluded roots are not visible to PyCharm. Usually, one would like to exclude temporary >build folders, generated output, logs, and other project output. Excluding the unnecessary >paths is a good way to significantly improve performance.
>
> This command is duplicated on the context menu of a content root.

Comment: I have excluded the directories but they continue to be indexed. See http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-52055 which LazyOne linked to.

Comment: This is probably because those folders are still in your library path; PyCharm will continue to index such folders unless you exclude them from the library; see http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-88958

Comment: With regard to the above comment by @DavidFraser -- Pycharm uses the $PYTHONPATH variable to index, so removing the directories from your python path on the command line may help. Also might try File --> Invalidate Caches / Restart in Pycharm after making the changes.

Comment: In PyCharm 2016, right click on the directory to exclude -> `Mark Directory As -> Excluded`.

Comment: There's an open feature request to automatically infer directories to exclude from the git ignore file, or at least provide an option towards that

Answer (score 23):

Besides @FooBarUser's suggestion, you can go to `Preferences->Editor->File Types` and here you have a box where you can add the files and folders you want to exclude from your project.

[image]

[image]

The folders and files that you include will not be shown in your project.

Comment: This really nailed it for me as, in my case, Pycharm was trying to index a bunch of eps files that I have scattered across the project folders.

Comment: Life saver! `Excluded` doesn't work for me at all.

Comment: Lifesaver, indeed. I had a reverse problem where I /wanted/ to see the `.pytest_cache` folder in my project tree purely out of convenience (while still excluding the rest). This place was where I added it back!

Answer (score 5):

In *PyCharm 2017.2.4* you can `cmd+shift+A` and start typing project structure... the `project structure` option should show up, then press `<enter>`. Then you can highlight the folder you want to exclude and mark it as `Exclude`. This is useful when you want to search for files with `cmd+shift+O` and you don't want `venv` files to showed up.

[image: project structure sidebar preview]

Answer (score 2):

As PyCharm (EC 2021.2) still suffers from the issue I take myself the liberty to answer what @LazyOne hinted in their comment 8 years ago.

While (as already mentioned) there are *excluded directories*, in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-5459 you can read that:

> ...indexing in PyCharm is performed at application level (and the
> index is shared between all projects), and the excluded directories
> are per-project. When PyCharm is indexing the interpreter paths, it's
> not possible to know whether any paths are excluded from any of the
> projects that the user has opened or might decide to open in the
> future.

and

> The issue happens *only* when your data folder is a subdirectory of a
> directory in your sys.path, which should be avoidable in most cases.

What helped in my case was unmarking the superdirectory as Sorce Roots (which removed it from `sys.path`).

Comment: removing the superdirectory from Sources Root wasn't an option for me, as it broke PyCharm's ability to recognize my app's import statements.  In my case, the solution was to ensure all the tools I was running that created output I didn't want indexed were doing so one directory up from my Sources Root (nox, coverage, etc).  No more "found 32,234 changed files...." messages.