# CSS file out of sync with my SCSS file

Tags: python, css, sass, pycharm

I'm a SASS newb and I have a concern. I'm using PyCharm and it seems like my work-flow for writing CSS using SASS would be to do ALL my work in the SCSS file and then link to the transpiled CSS file it generates for my HTML files.

But what happens if I make a lot of changes in the CSS file directly? Do those changes get blown out the next time my SCSS file gets transpiled?

In PyCharm I'm using a "SCSS" "File Watcher" with the "Track only root files" setting checked. So I'm not sure what this means for my CSS changes.

I'm concerned I'm going to end up with two different version files or that I might lose changes. Thanks for your help.

[image]

Comment: Isn't it "transpiled" CSS @Fabio? http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/file-watchers.html

Comment: Never heard that word in relation to SCSS, seems to be some made-up word for File Watchers, so changed it back to your original

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your CSS will be completely overwritten!  So don't do it this way!

The SCSS File Watcher compiles your SCSS into CSS, and will overwrite any CSS changes you've made.

The benefit of SCSS syntax vs the older SASS syntax is that SCSS encapsulates CSS syntax (and adds much more functionality).

So you can put regular CSS syntax into your SCSS files (and obviously you can use SCSS syntax as well).  Put all of your work into the SCSS files and you won't have anything overwritten.

**Update:**

To answer your question in the comments, you cannot prevent developers from writing to the css file (except maybe writing a script to change the file to read-only, but that's sort of hackey and easily overridden).

What I might suggest is that you use SASS' loud comment syntax, which will make a comment remain in the final css file even if you compress the output css (which you should be doing).

Just put an exclamation mark at the beginning of the comment like:

```
/*! Please do not edit this CSS file directly.  Make changes to the appropriate SASS files and recompile.  You have been warned... */
```

Comment: Is there a way to prevent developers from adding to the CSS file that will be constantly overwritten out?

Comment: I'm concerned about people not reading the comment and developers jumping to middle lines of the CSS file from an IDE shortcut. I was hoping for something that makes the file read only to everyone, but writeable from the File Watcher.

Comment: Ideally you should be compressing your output file.  I'm not sure what IDE shortcut you're talking about, but when you open up the compressed css file it should open up at the top.  you'll see the uncompress comments, and then a bunch of compressed css (which is really hard to read).

Comment: Very helpful, but still not idiot proof. In PyCharm if you hit the Shift key twice you could possible jump right to the code location of a CSS rule, make the change just to get overwritten later by somebody who transpiles the SCSS file.

Comment: No way around that unfortunately.  But I think that any developer who ended up opening a compressed CSS file is going to know that the file was not created that way.  So they're going to realize that something created that compressed file and you would hope they'd start digging around.  If you've followed standard sass conventions, there would be an scss or sass folder at the same level as the css folder.

Comment: I'm wondering if there's a way to exclude a CSS folder from my PyCharm project. This way other developers wouldn't be able to access it once inside the project.

Comment: This looks promising: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19024553/indexing-excluded-directories-in-pycharm-3